# Can't check output devices like speaker in Mozilla browser through WebRTC API

Tags: node.js, angular, webrtc

I want to check the output devices like speakers etc through WebRTC API. I've implemented the below code in Angular 5 and Node.

The WebRTC link is:
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/DetectRTC/

```
// for node.js users
var DetectRTC = require('detectrtc');
// non-nodejs users can skip above line
// below code will work for all users
console.log(DetectRTC.browser);

DetectRTC.load(function() {
    console.log(DetectRTC);
});
```

In Angular 5, the output devices e.g. Speaker status can be detected however, in Mozilla it says `NOPE` in "System has Speakers?" (see screen shot). In Node, everything is showing `false / NOPE` in mozilla / chrome browsers.

[image]

How can I detect the output devices e.g. Speaker in Mozilla for Angular? How can I detect all the status in Node?

Please note, the following code in JS also shows me the same output:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
      console.log(devices);
      devices = devices.filter((d) => d.kind === 'audioinput');
      console.log(devices);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The setSinkId API which is behind this functionality is not implemented in Firefox. [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1498512) has the details.